# Under Codeigniter, is it possible to see mysql_error()?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have an Codeigniter app (using version 2.1.0) that is writing a transaction to a mysql database. I'm fairly sure that I've got a foreign key constraint error occurring, but I can find no way to make CI tell me the specific error. mysql_error() comes back empty.

Can anyone tell me how to get Codeigniter to tell me the mysql error message?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, this is the mysql_error() wrapper.

```
$this->db->_error_message();
```

And the mysql_errno wrapper is:

```
$this->db->_error_number();
```

Comment: In the current version of CI, those are private functions. Any suggestions on the best way to get access to them with modifying the core files?

Comment: I don't get this, i mean how to use it. I Tried but get nothing in display.  @DRL

Comment: i've got this -> Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::_error_number(). i'm using php 5.6

Comment: This answer is deprecated. .check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843406/codeigniter-how-to-catch-db-errors

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use `call_function` in the db class to access `mysql_error`:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/call_function.html

Of course, you could also just turn on the debug flag in the DB config, to tell CI to display db errors:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html

> db_debug - TRUE/FALSE (boolean) -
>   Whether database errors should be
>   displayed.

Comment: When I attempt to use call_function('mysql_error'), I get the following:

"This feature is not available for the database you are using."

It is an innodb table under mysql.

I do have $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE in the database.php config file.

The most I get is my exception and a stack trace.

This is so frustrating. Right now, I'm feeling like going with CI was a big mistake.

Comment: @pbarney dont give up on it yet, check my answer

Comment: Also note, as mentioned on the `call_function` page, you're supposed to pass the name of the function **without** the `mysql_` prefix.