# CodeIgniter - how to catch DB errors?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a way to make *CI* throw an *exception* when it encounters a *DB error* instead of displaying a message like:

> A Database Error Occurred    Error Number: 1054
>           Unknown column 'foo' in 'where clause'    SELECT * FROM (`FooBar`) WHERE `foo` = '1'

NOTE: I only want this to happen in one controller. In the other controllers, I'm happy for it to display the *DB error messages*.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use `error()` method:

```
$this->db->error();
```

---

For CodeIgniter 2, you can use the following functions which are now deprecated:

```
$this->db->_error_message(); (mysql_error equivalent)
$this->db->_error_number(); (mysql_errno equivalent)
```

Comment: And when the queries are dinamically created, `$this->db->last_query()` useful too.

Comment: How do these prevent the messages from displaying?

Comment: You must turn debug off for database in config/database.php -> $db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;

Comment: Why is not possible to use Exception instead :-( ?

Comment: I'm with Thomas, I really there was a way to get these to throw exceptions by default.

Comment: These methods have been removed in CodeIgniter version 3. Use `$this->db->error()` instead. (see http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#handling-errors)

Comment: IMHO This does not answer the question. the `display_error` function ends with `exit(8)` therefore, you can't catch the exception. The only way is to disable db_debug as other answers told.

Answer (score 44):

Maybe this:

```
$db_debug = $this->db->db_debug; //save setting

$this->db->db_debug = FALSE; //disable debugging for queries

$result = $this->db->query($sql); //run query

//check for errors, etc

$this->db->db_debug = $db_debug; //restore setting
```

Comment: @RayJ Any idea why db_debug 'production' ENVIRONMENT default value (`'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'`) is set to FALSE in fresh downloaded CI v3? I see that setting it to false will show db error more details, which is not expected in production, right? I'm confused.

Comment: First we need to step back to the main index.php file and see how ENVIRONMENT is set and why.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051146/codeigniter3-why-would-serverci-env-ever-be-set-in-the-first-place

As we all know, this can set that to whatever: 

define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development') : to show errors while developing.

define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production') : when site is live.

So the line (in the database.php config) says:

'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),

Or

Set database debug mode to TRUE if "ENVIRONMENT" is not set to "production".

Answer (score 32):

In Codeigniter 3.0 (CI3), all you have to do is `$this->db->error()`

> If you need to get the last error that has occured, the error() method will return an array containing its code and message
>
> http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#handling-errors

Comment: Codeigniter halts code execution and outputs an error message if you have an error, so you will have no opportunity to check $this->db->error. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: @S.Imp - CodeIgniter only halts execution if config/database.php's `$db['default']['db_debug']` is true. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21073711/25507.

Answer (score 16):

You must turn debug off for database in config/database.php ->

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

It is better for your website security.

Answer (score 12):

I know this thread is old, but just in case there's someone else having this issue. This is a trick I used without touching the CI db classes. Leave your debug on and in your error view file, throw an exception.

So in you db config, you have :

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = true;
```

Then in your db error view file, mine is in `application/errors/error_db.php` replace all content with the following:

```
<?php
$message = preg_replace('/(<\/?p>)+/', ' ', $message);
throw new Exception("Database error occured with message : {$message}");

?>
```

Since the view file will be called, the error will always get thrown as an exception, you may later add different views for different environment.

Answer (score 12):

An example that worked for me:

```
$query = "some buggy sql statement";

$this->db->db_debug = false;

if(!@$this->db->query($query))
{
    $error = $this->db->error();
    // do something in error case
}else{
    // do something in success case
}
...
```

Answer (score 6):

I have created an simple library for that:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class exceptions {

    public function checkForError() {
        get_instance()->load->database();
        $error = get_instance()->db->error();
        if ($error['code'])
            throw new MySQLException($error);
    }
}

abstract class UserException extends Exception {
    public abstract function getUserMessage();
}

class MySQLException extends UserException {
    private $errorNumber;
    private $errorMessage;

    public function __construct(array $error) {
        $this->errorNumber = "Error Code(" . $error['code'] . ")";
        $this->errorMessage = $error['message'];
    }

    public function getUserMessage() {
        return array(
            "error" => array (
                "code" => $this->errorNumber,
                "message" => $this->errorMessage
            )
        );
    }

}
```

The example query:

```
function insertId($id){
    $data = array(
        'id' => $id,
    );

    $this->db->insert('test', $data);
    $this->exceptions->checkForError();
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

And I can catch it this way in my controller:

```
 try {
     $this->insertThings->insertId("1");
 } catch (UserException $error){
     //do whatever you want when there is an mysql error

 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Put this code in a file called MY_Exceptions.php in application/core folder:

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Class dealing with errors as exceptions
 */
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions
{

    /**
     * Force exception throwing on erros
     */
    public function show_error($heading, $message, $template = 'error_general', $status_code = 500)
    {
        set_status_header($status_code);

        $message = implode(" / ", (!is_array($message)) ? array($message) : $message);

        throw new CiError($message);
    }

}

/**
 * Captured error from Code Igniter
 */
class CiError extends Exception
{

}
```

It will make all the Code Igniter errors to be treated as Exception (CiError). Then, turn all your database debug on:

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it

```
    $this->db->_error_message();
```

It is better for finding error.After completing your site.
Close the error messages 
using it

```
    $db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

You will change it in your config folder's database.php

Answer (score 2):

Disable debugging of errors.

```
    $data_user = $this->getDataUser();
    $id_user   = $this->getId_user();

    $this->db->db_debug = false;
    $this->db->where(['id' => $id_user]);
    $res = $this->db->update(self::$table, $data_user['user']);

    if(!$res)
    {
        $error = $this->db->error();
        return $error;
        //return array $error['code'] & $error['message']
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If one uses PDO, additional to all the answers above.

I log my errors silently as below

```
        $q = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($query);

        if($q instanceof PDOStatement) {
           // go on with bind values and execute

        } else {

          $dbError = $this->db->error();
          $this->Logger_model->logError('Db Error', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), __METHOD__.' Line '.__LINE__, 'Code: '.$dbError['code'].' -  '.'Message: '.$dbError['message']);

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

In sybase_driver.php

```
/**
* Manejador de Mensajes de Error Sybase
* Autor: Isaí Moreno
* Fecha: 06/Nov/2019
*/

static  $CODE_ERROR_SYBASE;

public static function SetCodeErrorSybase($Code) {
    if ($Code != 3621) {  /*No se toma en cuenta el código de command aborted*/
        CI_DB_sybase_driver::$CODE_ERROR_SYBASE = trim(CI_DB_sybase_driver::$CODE_ERROR_SYBASE.' '.$Code);       
    }
}

public static function GetCodeErrorSybase() {               
    return CI_DB_sybase_driver::$CODE_ERROR_SYBASE;
}

public static function msg_handler($msgnumber, $severity, $state, $line, $text)
{       
    log_message('info', 'CI_DB_sybase_driver - CODE ERROR ['.$msgnumber.'] Mensaje - '.$text);
    CI_DB_sybase_driver::SetCodeErrorSybase($msgnumber);   
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Add and modify the following methods in the same sybase_driver.php file

```
/**
 * The error message number
 *
 * @access  private
 * @return  integer
 */
function _error_number()
{
    // Are error numbers supported?
    return CI_DB_sybase_driver::GetCodeErrorSybase();
}

function _sybase_set_message_handler()
{
    // Are error numbers supported?     
    return sybase_set_message_handler('CI_DB_sybase_driver::msg_handler');
}
```

Implement in the function of a controller.

```
public function Eliminar_DUPLA(){       
    if($this->session->userdata($this->config->item('mycfg_session_object_name'))){     
        //***/
        $Operacion_Borrado_Exitosa=false;
        $this->db->trans_begin();

        $this->db->_sybase_set_message_handler();  <<<<<------- Activar Manejador de errores de sybase
        $Dupla_Eliminada=$this->Mi_Modelo->QUERY_Eliminar_Dupla($PARAMETROS);                   

        if ($Dupla_Eliminada){
            $this->db->trans_commit();
            MostrarNotificacion("Se eliminó DUPLA exitosamente","OK",true);
            $Operacion_Borrado_Exitosa=true;
        }else{
            $Error = $this->db->_error_number();  <<<<----- Obtengo el código de error de sybase para personilzar mensaje al usuario    
            $this->db->trans_rollback();                
            MostrarNotificacion("Ocurrio un error al intentar eliminar Dupla","Error",true);
            if ($Error == 547) {
                MostrarNotificacion("<strong>Código de error :[".$Error.']. No se puede eliminar documento Padre.</strong>',"Error",true);
            }  else {                   
                MostrarNotificacion("<strong>Código de Error :[".$Error.']</strong><br>',"Error",true);                 
            }
        }

        echo "@".Obtener_Contador_Notificaciones();
        if ($Operacion_Borrado_Exitosa){
            echo "@T";
        }else{
            echo "@F";
        }
    }else{
        redirect($this->router->default_controller);
    }

}
```

In the log you can check the codes and messages sent by the database server.

```
INFO - 2019-11-06 19:26:33 -> CI_DB_sybase_driver - CODE ERROR [547] Message - Dependent foreign key constraint violation in a referential integrity constraint. dbname = 'database', table name = 'mitabla', constraint name = 'FK_SR_RELAC_REFERENCE_SR_mitabla'. INFO - 2019-11-06 19:26:33 -> CI_DB_sybase_driver - CODE ERROR [3621] Message - Command has been aborted. ERROR - 2019-11-06 19:26:33 -> Query error: - Invalid query: delete from mitabla where ID = 1019.
```

Comment: Please answer in English as this is an English website!