# MySql join query is working on local server but not working on live server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have made a project that's join query is working in local server, but not working on live server.

Live server shows an error as

> Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in
>   /home/a3608717/public_html/CI/application/models/student_model.php on
>   line 157

```
public function fetch_all_sbj(){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT s.*,ct.* 
                               from subject s INNER JOIN courseTerm ct   
                                 ON s.sbjId=ct.cTId");

    return $query->result(); ///This is 157 line   
}
```

If I write this query as

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from subject ");
```

or

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from courseTerm ");
```

The there is no error, But I need to join them.
Similary, Problem also all of the query. Please help me.

Comment: there is no reason for same query to fail on live server unless its not connecting to DB via your script or connecting to a wrong DB or tables are not there in live

Comment: If there is a db connection error ? How they work when I change the query that i prescribed before.

Comment: The error probably means that `$query` is `null` which would most likely be the case if there are no results returned by the query. Check in your DB-class if `query()` returns `null` if the result is empty. Do you have the exact same datasets in your production tables as in your local tables?

Comment: Quasdunk,

Exactly you catch. I check it using var_dump but the query empty when it is join.

Comment: The is almost certainly a difference between your production and dev databases. What happens when you run the query directly on the database using a mysql client?

Comment: Ok :) So you should fix your DB-class accordingly or check if `$query` is not null before calling `result()` on it and everything should work fine again :)

Comment: you might want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843406/codeigniter-how-to-catch-db-errors to see if there is useful error information when it fails. Also, use `$this->db->last_query()` to see if there are any surprises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed your database class name. It is necessary.
May be you have written you model class name as

```
  class event_model extends CI_Model and change it
  class Event_model extends CI_Model
  also change your db collaborate in config.php
```