# Can't catch my mysql errors

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for my server side in php.

I set my email field UNIQUE on my Users table.
The problem is that whatever I tried I can't catch the error mysql generated when trying to insert a duplicate email.

What i tried inside my model:

```
function insert($arr) {

    $query=  $this->CI->db->insert('user', $arr);
    if($query){
        return $this->CI->db->insert_id();
    } else {
        $msg = $this->CI-db->_error_message();

    return  $msg;

    }

}
```

The issues goes that everything is fine until I get a duplicate and I actually get NOTHING inside the $msg. I know debug is on from the database config file.

Comment: what is your codeigniter version?

Comment: 3.0.0 - i upgraded from 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your database config `'db_debug' => TRUE,` your code will exit with showing the error message and you will not able to reach this line `$msg = $this->CI-db->_error_message();`.

So to catch the error message you need to set the.

```
db_debug' => FALSE
```

At CI-2 your above code will work.[See more at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843406/codeigniter-how-to-catch-db-errors)

But At CI-3 those function is not available and it will produce php undefined method error. CI-3 has a method [display_error](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/db_driver_reference.html?highlight=db%20error#CI_DB_driver::display_error). You can check it.

**My solution:** If you want the errors you can get it using this line

```
$msg = $this->db->conn_id->error_list;
```

This will give you the error lists as array.But remember you need to set `db_debug' => FALSE`

Comment: how do i work with error_list when i try to return it i get "Message: Array to string conversion". i just want to return it and print to screen.

Comment: yes it returns array of all errors.If you want last error you can use `$this->db->conn_id->error` your case it should be `$this->CI->db->conn_id->error`.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam Any idea why db_debug 'production' ENVIRONMENT default value ('db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production') is set to FALSE in fresh downloaded CI v3? I see that setting it to false will show db error more details, which is not expected in production, right? I'm confused because in explanation of variables (config/database.php): ['db_debug'] TRUE/FALSE - Whether database errors should be displayed. But in fact, FALSE shows the database errors.

Comment: `db_debug' => TRUE` shows the error. and `FALSE` do not shows the error. `ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'` is true because default environment is development and shows the errors.Obvious you do not want to show errors on your production environment.