# Codeigniter, call multiple DB's

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am very new to codeigniter,but dealing with an issue regarding multiple db's. The databases are located on the same host.

I have changed the database.php file to include an extra group aside from 'default' new group is called 'social'

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_group = 'social';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'xxxx';
$db['default']['username'] = 'xxx';
$db['default']['password'] = 'xxxx';
$db['default']['database'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

$db['social']['hostname'] = 'xxx';
$db['social']['username'] = 'xxx';
$db['social']['password'] = 'xxx';
$db['social']['database'] = 'social';
$db['social']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['social']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['social']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['social']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['social']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['social']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['social']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['social']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['social']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['social']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['social']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Now in my code i call the dbs

```
public function __construct()
{
    $dbgroup = !file_exists(".git") ? "default" : "development";
    $this->_time = microtime(true);
    $this->_db =& DB($dbgroup);

    $dbgroup = "social";
    $this->_time = microtime(true);
    $this->_dbs =& DB($dbgroup);
```

What am i doing wrong, why cant i use _dbs to fetch data from the second db? Keep in mind... totally coding newbie here! this is not my day job :)

UPDATE!
Tried calling the db in this function as described in stackoverflow.com/a/8269596, but i still can't get it to work.

```
public function getUsers($userid = NULL)
{
    if (empty($userid) ) {
                $rs = $this->load->database('social', TRUE);
        ->select("id, username")
        ->from("user")
        ->get();
        $userid = $rs->result();
    return $userid;
    }
    elseif (isset($userid)) {
                $rs = $this->load->database('social', TRUE);
        ->select("id, username")
        ->from("user")
        ->where('id', $userid)
        ->get();
        $userid = $rs->result();
    return $userid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which CodeIgniter version are you using?

Comment: I recommend looking at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8269596 and specifically this line `$otherdb = $this->load->database('otherdb', TRUE);`

Comment: Tried it, but cant get it to work

`if (empty($userid) ) {
     $rs = $this->load->database('social', TRUE);
   ->select("id, username")
   ->from("pricecloud_user")
   ->get();

   $userid = $rs->result();
  return $userid;
  }
  elseif (isset($userid)) {
     $rs = $this->load->database('social', TRUE);
   ->select("id, username")
   ->from("user")
   ->where('id', $userid)
   ->get();

   $userid = $rs->result();
   
   
  return $userid;
  }`

Comment: I cannot read that, please update your question with the code so that it's easier to read. Thank you

Comment: Oh sorry, makes sense... just updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
public function getUsers($userid = NULL)
{
    $rs = $this->load->database('social', TRUE);
    if (empty($userid) ) {
        $rs->select("id, username")
        ->from("user")
        ->get();
        $userid = $rs->result();
    return $userid;
    }
    elseif (isset($userid)) {
        $rs->select("id, username")
        ->from("user")
        ->where('id', $userid)
        ->get();
        $userid = $rs->result();
    return $userid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, however no luck, dont even get a usable error

Comment: @NicolaiHolmøThomsen I recommend contacting a professional developer.

Comment: @NicolaiHolmøThomsen You can try setting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your page or check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843406/codeigniter-how-to-catch-db-errors for CodeIgniter specific error handling but I think your initial issue of connecting to a different DB has likely been solved based on the code snippet you provided.

Comment: i finally succeeded... you suggestion actually did help, however i also did not have the correct user permissions, so after this was changed as well everything worked... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NicolaiHolmøThomsen That's great to hear! I'm glad you got it sorted out because I do not think I would have guessed that you needed to fix user permissions as well :)