# What does "export CI_ENV" mean in code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

What I'm trying to achieve is manage cron jobs by saving them into my database, then writing one generic job which runs every minute and triggers the jobs saved in the database.

I found this piece of code in a code igniter library which I saw [here](https://www.heatware.net/programming-php/manage-cron-jobs-database-codeigniter/)

```
$env = getenv('CI_ENV');
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $cmd = "export CI_ENV={$env} && {$row->command}";
    $output = shell_exec($cmd);
    //do other things
}
```

I do not understand what this line `$cmd = "export CI_ENV={$env} && {$row->command}";` is really doing. I do not understand what `export` is doing there.

Comment: what is CI_ENV https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051146/codeigniter3-why-would-serverci-env-ever-be-set-in-the-first-place   and what is `shell export`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411455/what-does-export-do-in-shell-programming

Comment: Have seen the links but I still don't understand why the export keyword is in that line.

Comment: remove it if you don't need CI_env variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export` is a Linux command used to define a variable (and its value) in the BASH working "space". So, the line `export CI_ENV={$env}` is saying define a var named CI_ENV with a value of `$env` that I can use in BASH or other shell scripts.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense now