# Codeigniter3: How to get error or success info from db->insert?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I would like to get return info from `$CI->db->insert(...)`, both on success and failure.

I have tried to simply catch the return and echo it and print_r it, but neither gives me anything useful; And I have tried $CI->db->display_errors() (though I did not actually find it listed at [CI docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)).

```
$return = $this->db->insert( "some_table" , $table_data ) ;

print_r( $return  ) ; // 
// OR
print  ( $this->db->display_errors() ) ;
```

Does `$CI->db->insert(...)` offer a way to check success/failure?

---

**UPDATES:**

in CI3 ...

`$this->db->_error_message()` generates an error: 
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::_error_message()` *(with or without the leading underscore)*.

`$this->db->display_errors()` generates an error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::display_errors()`

`$this->db->insert_id()` generates a `0` *(regardless of whether the insert succeeds or fails)*

Comment: see this url: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#handling-errors

Comment: and also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843406/codeigniter-how-to-catch-db-errors

Comment: use if ( $this->db->_error_message() ) echo $this->db->_error_message() ;

Comment: @AldoZumaran These methods have been removed in CodeIgniter version 3.

Answer (score 4):

`$this->db->_error_message()` is deprecated so instead of that try use following function.

```
$error = $this->db->error();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods that give me *meaningful* info, though I haven't seen in the CI3 documentation that the info is *definitive*, thus I consider this a **weak-ish** solution:

---

**A ...**

`$return = $this->db->insert( "some_table" , $lvl_data )` returns...

```
// on SUCCESS: 1 ......... which indicates the boolean TRUE, not the number 1
// on FAILURE: nothing ... which indicates the boolean FALSe
```

However, I do not know from the docs if this is definitively always ensured.

*PLEASE NOTE:* this will generate an uncatch-able formatted CI error message on *failure*, unless you use affect $this->db->db_debug ... *see working example below for usage*.

---

**B ...**

`$this->db->error()`  returns...

```
// on SUCCESS: Array ( [code] => 0    [message] => ) 
// on FAILURE: Array ( [code] => 1054 [message] => Unknown column 'some_bad_column_name' in 'field list' )
```

However, I do not know for certain (based on [CI3 doc](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#handling-errors)) that `[code]=>0` necessarily equals `success`.

---

**A+B, with $this->db->db_debug ...**

Thus I believe that combining these two infos is loosely indicative:

```
$db_debug           = $this->db->db_debug ; //save setting
$this->db->db_debug = FALSE               ; //disable debugging for queries

$return = $this->db->insert( "some_table" , $lvl_data ) ;
$error  = $this->db->error ()                           ;
if ( $error['code'] === 0  &&  $return === true )
  { // almost surely SUCCESS
  }

$this->db->db_debug = $db_debug           ; //set it back
```