# When I Use Query Builder Function then Error message not show

Tags: codeigniter

When I Use Query Builder Function in codeIgniter, then Error message not shown.

**Here Is a Controller**

```
<?php
class Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function demo()
    {
        $this->load->model("Model");

        $data["name"] = $this->input->post("text");
        $res = $this->Model->add_data($data);
        echo $res;
    }
}
?>
```

**Here Is a Model**

```
<?php
class Model extends CI_Model
{
    public function add_data($data)
    {
        if ( ! $this->db->insert("table_name",$data))
        {
            $error = $this->db->error();
            return $error["message"];
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter - how to catch DB errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843406/codeigniter-how-to-catch-db-errors)

Comment: @A.Developer can you tell me your CI_VERSION?

Comment: My CI Version is 3.1.9

Answer (score 1):

**Try this in your model**

```
$data = array(
    'title' => 'My title',
    'name' => 'My Name',
    'date' => 'My date'
);

$sql = $this->db->set($data)->get_compiled_insert('mytable');
echo $sql;
if (!$this->db->simple_query($sql)) {
    $error = $this->db->error(); // Has keys 'code' and 'message'
}
echo'<pre>';print_r($error);die;
```

INSERT INTO `mytable` (`title`, `name`, `date`) VALUES ('My title', 'My Name', 'My date')

Array
(
    [code] => 1146
    [message] => Table 'db.mytable' doesn't exist
)

Comment: I want to use $this->db->insert() instead of $this->db->simple_query().

Comment: $this->db->insert() will return last inserted ID only if a primary key is there or 0 so you cannot check it in if which is not feasible

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your model and display it :

In CodeIgniter 3 like **@Viren Panchal** said, use this : error();

In your example :

```
$this->db->db_debug = false; 
$res = $this->Model->add_data($data); 
if(!$res) { 
    $error = $this->db->error(); 
    echo $error; 
}
```

Comment: I put this code.But here I same problem faced.Have any example ?

Comment: `$this->db->db_debug = false;
$res = $this->Model->add_data($data);

    if(!$res)
    {
        $error = $this->db->_error_message();
        echo $error;
    }`

Comment: These methods `$this->db->_error_message()` and `$this->db->_error_number()` have been removed in CodeIgniter version 3. You can use $this->db->error() instead.